# ionic nvd3 how to remove top number/value in Y-axis stackedAreaChart

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, graph, nvd3.js

I have this stackedAreaChart and it has this top value/number 106,794 which I want to remove on the Y-axis. How do I remove that top value ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwN1j.jpg

Here is my nvd3 code:
https://pastebin.com/ignt23rE

```
                  yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'ktoe',
                    axisLabelDistanc: 40,
                    tickFormat: d3.format(',')

                  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing

```
showMaxMin: false
```